# Como evitar que el boton dropdown de bootstrap se oculte al hacer click dentro de el?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente boton: es un dropdown, no pongo el codigo completo por que no es necesario.

```html
 <button type="button" onclick="dropdownEvent(this);" class="btn btn-link text-default btn-herramienta" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Color de fondo
                        </button>
```

El dropdown funciona bien, lo que quiero es evitar que se cierra automaticamente cuando le doy click dentro de el y cuando se de click fuera de el pues que se cierre, como haria eso? gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas. Necesitamos el código de jQuery o JS que estés usando para poder corregirlo. Solo has puesto el html. Un saludo.

Comment: Amigo el codigo que se encarga de abrir el dropdown es de bootstrap, yo no estoy agregando un codigo adicional, lo que quiero es evitar que se cierre al hacer click dentro de el, eh estado investigando y no encuentro nada relacionado, tu no tienes idea de alguna funcion js? gracias.

Comment: Has mirado lo que hace la función que tienes en tu código? Lo mismo la puedes retocar para que te funcione como quieres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cogí el código de ejemplo de `dropdown` de `bootstrap` de la siguiente 
[pagina](https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(`${e.target.textContent} clicado!`);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Ejemplo dropdown
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Primera opcion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Segunda opcion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tercera opcion</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

La idea es que debes "capturar" cuando haces click y cancelar la desaparición del elemento, sustituyendolo por lo que quieras.

Comment: Excelente amigo! muchas gracias!