# Evitar que se cierre dropdown al apretar enlace/botón

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un dropdown que dentro tiene diferentes elementos, entre estos destacan más dropdowns y también botones.

Inicialmente este dropdown (menú) solo tenía dropdowns (sub-menús) en su interior, con la siguiente estructura. Es de este [post en su respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation), simplemente cambié nombres y añadí o quite sub-menús en función de mis datos.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass('show');
  });


  return false;
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>



            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Lo bueno que proporciona este código es que al hacer click en el sub-menú no se cierra todo, si no que se abre (obviamente lo deseado). Pues los dropdowns tienen como norma, que al clickar sobre un enlace, este se cierra.

La cosa es que los enlaces que aparecen aquí, cierran el dropdown todavía y a mi eso para algunos no me interesa, pues actúan a modo de filtro y no quiero que se cierre.

Leyendo este otro [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245052/como-evitar-que-el-boton-dropdown-de-bootstrap-se-oculte-al-hacer-click-dentro-d), vi que la clave está en `.stopPropagation()` pero no consigo saber como implementarlo en el javascript anterior para que funcione. He pensado en meter un condicional más en el que busque una clase concreta que le se le de a estos enlaces especiales que no se han de cerrar, por ejemplo `class = "filters-drop"` y aquí aplicar el `.stopPropagation()` pero no me funciona y encima rompe también lo que se conseguía anteriormente.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass('show');
  });

  if ($(this).hasClass('filters-drop')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  return false;
});
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme por favor?

Muchas gracias, un saludo y salud para todos.